# A problem on unitary spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, quadratic-forms

If $V$ is a unitary space with a hermitian form $\langle,\rangle$ and $v_1,...v_n$ are any $n$ vectors in $V$ then is it true that ${\rm det}(\langle v_i,v_j\rangle)\geq 0$?

When does equality hold?

Comment: By hermitian form you mean a complex valued almost-inner product, but with $\;\langle u,v\rangle=\overline{\langle v,u\rangle}\;$ ?

Comment: Yes, and by a unitary space I mean a f.d. complex vector space with the inner product being positive-definite.